# How to get the current screen resolution on windows via command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, display, powershell, resolution

I'm trying get the **current** screen resolution on windows via command line.
Based on most of the answers I've found, I should use:

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenweight
```

But this returns the **max** supported resolution of the display device, **not the current one**, which is what I need.

Example:
I'm using a 4k monitor, but currently set to display only at `1920x1080`. When I run the command above, I get:

```
ScreenHeight  ScreenWidth
2160          3840
```

[image]

How do I get the **current screen resolution** on windows via command line?

Comment: Interesting, Why would you need this exactly?

Comment: I'm developing a multi OS app in python that needs to get current screen resolution via command line. I'm trying to avoid 3rd party libraries and stick with the default OS binaries  or python builtin functions only.

Comment: This question has already been asked at StackOverflow and Server Fault. You may need to use PowerShell. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967699/get-screen-resolution-using-wmi-powershell-in-windows-7   and    https://serverfault.com/questions/825360/how-to-get-the-screen-resolution-in-windows-10-with-command-prompt-or-powershell

Comment: It's not duplicate, but actually a good example of what's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with high DPI made this somewhat challenging because most Windows API functions return a scaled version of the resolution for compatibility unless the application declares high DPI awareness. Inspired by [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21450169/2825369) I wrote this PowerShell script:

```
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class PInvoke {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")] public static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);
}
"@
$hdc = [PInvoke]::GetDC([IntPtr]::Zero)
[PInvoke]::GetDeviceCaps($hdc, 118) # width
[PInvoke]::GetDeviceCaps($hdc, 117) # height
```

It outputs two lines: first the horizontal resolution, then the vertical resolution.

To run it, save it to a file (e.g. `screenres.ps1`) and launch it with PowerShell:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\screenres.ps1
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.
Try this:

```
wmic PATH Win32_VideoController GET CurrentVerticalResolution,CurrentHorizontalResolution
```